# Converting a list of points to a numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using genfromtxt to import essentially a 2D array that has all its values listed in a text file of the form (x's and y's are integers):

```
    x1   y1   z1
    x2   y2   z2
    :    :    :
```

I'm using the for loop below but I'm pretty sure there must be a one line way to do it. What would be a more efficient way to do this conversion?

```
raw = genfromtxt(file,skip_header = 6)

xrange = ( raw[:,0].min() , raw[:,0].max() )
yrange = ( raw[:,1].min() , raw[:,1].max() )

Z = zeros(( xrange[1] - xrange[0] +1 , yrange[1] - yrange[0] +1 ))

for row in raw:
    Z[ row[0]-xrange[0] , row[1]-yrange[0] ] = row[2]
```

Comment: The first question should be why are you using genfromtxt? Are there missing values in the input? Do you really want the starting point for these calculations to be a masked array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the for loop with the following:

```
xidx = (raw[:,0]-xrange[0]).astype(int)
yidx = (raw[:,1]-yrange[0]).astype(int)

Z[xidx, yidx] = raw[:,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

To import a matrix from a file you can just split the lines and then convert to int.

```
[[int(i) for i in j.split()] for j in open('myfile').readlines()]
```

of course, I'm supposing your file contains only the matrix.

At the end, you can convert this 2-D array to numpy.

Comment: Why is this better than the easier import function ``genfromtxt`` (or ``loadtxt`` will do in this case) of numpy?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
>>> Z = zeros((3, 3))
>>> test = array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 1, 6], [2, 0, 4]])
>>> Z[test[:, 0:2].T.tolist()]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> Z[test[:, 0:2].T.tolist()] = test[:, 2]
>>> Z
array([[ 0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  0.,  0.]])
```

In your case:

```
Z[(raw[:, 0:2] - minimum(raw[:, 0:2], axis=0)).T.tolist()] = raw[:, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also go with `numpy.searchsorted` which will also allow for non-equally spaced / float data:

```
raw = genfromtxt(file,skip_header = 6)

xvalues = numpy.sorted(set(raw[:,0]))
xidx = numpy.searchsorted(xvalues, raw[:,0])

yvalues = numpy.sorted(set(raw[:,1]))
yidx = numpy.searchsorted(yvalues, raw[:,1])

Z = numpy.zeros((len(xvalues), len(yvalues)))
Z[xidx, yidx] = raw[:,2]
```

Otherwise, I would be following Simon's answer.